# U-SQL Query Error in Azure Data Lake

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am getting an error in U-SQL query:

```
E_CSC_USER_SYNTAXERROR: syntax error. Expected one of: '.' ALL ANTISEMIJOIN ANY AS BROADCASTLEFT BROADCASTRIGHT CROSS DISTINCT EXCEPT FULL FULLCROSS GROUP HASH HAVING INDEXLOOKUP INNER INTERSECT JOIN LEFT LOOP MERGE ON OPTION ORDER OUTER OUTER UNION PAIR PIVOT PRESORT PRODUCE READONLY REQUIRED RIGHT SAMPLE SEMIJOIN SERIAL SORTED TO UNIFORM UNION UNIVERSE UNPIVOT USING WHERE WITH ';' '(' ')' ','
Line 19
Component
CSC
Message
syntax error. Expected one of: '.' ALL ANTISEMIJOIN ANY AS BROADCASTLEFT BROADCASTRIGHT CROSS DISTINCT EXCEPT FULL FULLCROSS GROUP HASH HAVING INDEXLOOKUP INNER INTERSECT JOIN LEFT LOOP MERGE ON OPTION ORDER OUTER OUTER UNION PAIR PIVOT PRESORT PRODUCE READONLY REQUIRED RIGHT SAMPLE SEMIJOIN SERIAL SORTED TO UNIFORM UNION UNIVERSE UNPIVOT USING WHERE WITH ';' '(' ')' ','
Resolution
Correct the script syntax, using expected token(s) as a guide.
Description
Invalid syntax found in the script.
Details
at token 'string', line 19
near the ###:
**************

    Custom string,
    ttl int
    FROM @INPUT_FILE
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor("$.[*]");

@jsonnodes =
    Partition  ### string, 
    SELECT JsonApp.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(System).Values AS system_array,
    SELECT JsonApp.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Custom).Values AS custom_array,
```

Here is my u-sql query:

```
@json =
    EXTRACT 
    Partition string, 
    System string,
    Custom string,
    ttl int
    FROM @INPUT_FILE
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor("$.[*]");

@jsonnodes =
    Partition string, 
    SELECT JsonApp.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(System).Values AS system_array,
    SELECT JsonApp.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Custom).Values AS custom_array,
    ttl
    FROM @json;
```

I am getting the error, while extracting the values in the @jsonnodes query.

Also, what json path should be used to go through all the objects in the JSON?

Answer (score 2):

To correct Simon's answer:

The original script used invalid syntax (a column name/type pair outside of a SELECT or EXTRACT and then several SELECT clauses in a single query):

```
@jsonnodes =
  Partition string, 
  SELECT JsonApp.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(System).Values AS system_array,
  SELECT JsonApp.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Custom).Values AS custom_array,
  ttl
  FROM @json;
```

You probably just want to select the already extracted column and the individual expressions, so you move the name (**without the type!**) into the `SELECT` statement and only use **one** `SELECT` clause as follows:

```
@jsonnodes =
SELECT 
    Partition, 
    JsonApp.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(System).Values AS system_array,
    JsonApp.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Custom).Values AS custom_array,
    ttl
FROM @json;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like in SQL you can use SELECT only once in your statement, like you did for the EXTRACT statement, so your code should look like this:

```
@jsonnodes =
SELECT 
    Partition string, 
    JsonApp.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(System).Values AS system_array,
    JsonApp.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Custom).Values AS custom_array,
    ttl
FROM @json;
```

When you look at the JSON path examples [here](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) you can see that  you can use the $..* path to take all objects or $[*] for only first level objects.